# Inserting value in array table js

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following array table:

```js
var ticket1 = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];
```

I want to insert values in the above array. How do I do that?

I have tried this:

```js
ticket1[0, 0] = 20;
ticket[1, 0] = 30;
ticket[2, 0] = 40;
```

Expected result:

```js
[20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Actual result:

```js
[20, 30, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: ticket1[0][0] = 20; You can Use this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can call the index of the array and then will need to call the index of the second array. `ticket1[0][0] = 20;`.

Comment: thanks ozer. thanks twisty. i will try this

Comment: @ozer and #twisty both of them are correct. Their solution works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ticket1[0][0] = 20;
```

posted by ozer and twisty

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  var ticket1 = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  ];

  ticket1[0][0] = 20;
  ticket1[1][0] = 30;
  ticket1[2][0] = 40;

  $.each(ticket1, function(k, v) {
    $("<p>").html(v.join(", ")).appendTo("div");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

When using a Matrix, or an Array of Arrays, you still access each Array Index. So `ticket1[0]` will access the first element, which is an Array of Integers, so `ticket1[0][0]` accesses the first index of the first array.

You can make a more complex function to update / change elements in the Matrix.

```js
Array.prototype.mPush = function(x, y, e) {
  this[x][y] = e;
  return this;
}

$(function() {
  var ticket1 = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  ];

  ticket1.mPush(0, 0, 20);
  ticket1.mPush(1, 0, 30);
  ticket1[2][0] = 40;

  $.each(ticket1, function(k, v) {
    $("<p>").html(v.join(", ")).appendTo("div");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`function add(var){ 
      ticket.push(var)
}`

Eg:
ticket.push(2)